# Why does this associative array return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I don't know why this isn't working. I thought I've seen this in use a dozen times but it appears that I looked at it the wrong way judging from this:

```
var array = ["dog", "cat"];
console.log(array["dog"]); // undefined, why?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var array = {dog: "dog", cat: "cat"};
console.log(array["dog"]); // defined, why?
```

What you have is not an associative array, it does not act as such. A [**JavaScript object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2c_Variables%2c_and_Literals#Object_Literals) acts as such. The object's literals are `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: @David this is the way to do it, and it works for me... Even if I copy/paste this straight into my address bar it works... `javascript:var array = {dog: "dog", cat: "cat"}; alert(array["dog"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't set a value for the key "dog".

```
var array = {"dog":"woof", "cat":"meow"}
console.log(array["dog"]); // returns woof
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an associative array. As a matter of fact, associative arrays don't exist in JavaScript. If you want something which behaves similarly, use an object:

```
var animals = {dog: 123, cat: 456};
console.log(animals["dog"], animals.dog);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made an array with two elements:

```
array[0] = 'dog'
array[1] = 'cat'
```

This is not an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

its not an associative array, just a regular array.

```
console.log(array[0]); // will give you dog
```

if you want associative array behavior create an object like so:

```
var dictionary = {"dog":"woof", "cat":"meow"};
console.log(dictionary["dog"]);
```